# HTTPException: Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: #deadline

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api-python-client, deadlines

We are using the developers python guide with Python data 2.15 library and as per example stated for app engine.
createSite("test site one", description="test site one", source_site =("https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/googleappsforus.com/google-site-template" ))

We are getting an un-predictable response every time we use.

**Exception:** HTTPException: Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/googleappsforyou.com

Did someone experience the same issue? Is it AppEngine or Sites API related?

Regards,

Comment: FYI: You should tag this issue correctly under the google-appengine category and possibly also the Google API client (if that exists).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

*Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL* is actually a **DeadlineExceededError**. When you are making a HTTP request, App Engine maps this request to URLFetch. URLFetch has its own deadline that is configurable. See the [URLFetch documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview).

It seems that your client library catches DeadlineExceededError and throws HTTPException. Your client library either passes a deadline to URLFetch (which you would need to change) or the default deadline is insufficient for your request.

Try setting the default URLFetch deadline like this:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(45)
```

Also make sure to check out [Dealing with DeadlineExceededErrors](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors) in the official Docs.

Keep in mind that any end-user initiated request must complete in 60 seconds or will encounter a DeadlineExceededError. See [App Engine Python Runtime Request Timer](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#The_Request_Timer).

Comment: Hi Bernd, Thanks for your response. Even after we increased the Fetch time to 45 seconds, we are still experiencing deadline issues - we created about 50 sites in a day, out of which 25% of them failed due to deadline exceptions. How do we deal with deadline exceptions? What are some of the work arounds? We create every day about ~30-40 sites and would like to address this issue if we can.Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: The import is actually: `from google.appengine.api import urlfetch`

Comment: If the content you are fetching cannot be fetched within 60 seconds minus the overhead for your request handler, you will need to fetch (call) the URLs from a request initiated by a TaskQueue or a request running on Backend. When using either of these approaches you can increase the deadline to as much as 10 minutes.

Comment: @Bernd Verst Is there any way where we can handle this exception ? I am getting Process terminated because the request deadline was exceeded. (Error code 123) error.

Comment: @BerndVerst i am getting the same error. In my app it endpoint make db connection ,get data and closes connection and return data. But it is throwing error code 123. As i checked there was 900 database connection and 150+ instances were up. I restarted my db and problem is solved? what is the reason how can i solve that ?

Answer (score 9):

The accepted solution did not work for me when working with the very recent versions of `httplib2` and `googleapiclient`.  The problem appears to be that `httplib2.Http` passes it's timeout argument all the way through to `urlfetch`.  Since it has a default value of `None`, `urlfetch` sets the limit for that request to 5s irrespective of whatever default you set with `urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline`.  It appears that you have a few options.

First option -- You can explicitly pass an instance of `httplib2.Http` around:

```
http = httplib2.Http(timeout=30)
...
client.method().execute(http=http)
```

Second option, you can set the default value using sockets<sup>1</sup>:

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(30)
```

Third option, you can tell appengine to use sockets for requests<sup>2</sup>.  To do that, you [modify `app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/#making_httplib_use_sockets):

```
env_variables:
   GAE_USE_SOCKETS_HTTPLIB : 'anyvalue'
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>This *might* only work for paid apps since the socket api might not be present for unpaid apps...</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup>I'm almost certain this will only work for paid apps since the socket api won't be functional for unpaid apps...</sup>