# Is threading.local() a safe way to store variables for a single request in Google AppEngine?

Tags: python, multithreading, google-app-engine, global-variables, python-multithreading

I have a google appengine app where I want to set a global variable for that request only. Can I do this?

In request_vars.py

```
# request_vars.py

global_vars = threading.local()
```

In another.py

```
# another.py

from request_vars import global_vars
get_time():
    return global_vars.time_start
```

In main.py

```
# main.py

import another
from request_vars import global_vars

global_vars.time_start = datetime.datetime.now()

time_start = another.get_time()
```

Questions: Considering multithreading, concurrent requests, building on Google AppEngine, and hundreds (even thousands) of requests per second, will the value of `time_start` always be equal to the value set in `global_vars.time_start` in `main.py` per request? Is this safe to use with multithreading/threadsafe enabled?

Comment: In addition to the answer below, when using appengine you can use the environment for local storage, it's contents only exist for the current request. This does not necessarily hold true for non appengine environments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, using `threading.local` is an excellent method to set a per-request global. Your request will always be handled by one thread, on one instance in the Google cloud. That thread local value will be unique to that thread.

Take into account that the thread *can* be reused for future requests, and always reset the value at the start of the request.